# font-family is not working in css although the structure is ok

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm using the following structure in a website:

- Root

  - theme

    - `index.html`
  - assets

    - myfont

      - css

         `fontiran.css` and `style.css`
      - fonts

         `IRANSansWeb.eot` , `IRANSansWeb.woff`, `IRANSansWeb.woff2`, and `IRANSansWeb.ttf`

And the contents are:

index.html:

```
[...]
<link href="../assets/myfont/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
[...]
```

style.css:

```
@import url(fontiran.css);
body {
    font-family: IRANSans !important;
}
```

fontiran.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

But the font is not working on the website. `FontFinder` plugin for firefox shows:

```
Font
===============================
font-family (stack): IRANSans
Font being rendered: System Default
font-size: 13px
```

But it's not being used. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

[Only Internet Explorer supports EOT files](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot).

Use WOFF and WOFF 2 instead as [they have decently wide browser support](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Comment: ttf, woff and woff2 are included in [Other types]. I skipped them for readability reasons only.